# Why the gs segment register is address is set to 0x0000000000000000 on visual studio x64(MASM)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, masm, masm64

I am currently reading ["The Ultimate Anti Debugging Reference"](https://anti-reversing.com/Downloads/Anti-Reversing/The_Ultimate_Anti-Reversing_Reference.pdf) and I am trying to implement some of the techniques.

To check the Value of the NtglobalFlag they use this code -

```
 push 60h
 pop rsi
 gs:lodsq ;Process Environment Block
 mov al, [rsi*2+rax-14h] ;NtGlobalFlag
 and al, 70h
 cmp al, 70h
 je being_debugged
```

I did all the correct adjustments for running x64 code on visual studio 2017 I used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHE0txCjGgI&list=PL0C5C980A28FEE68D&index=1) tutorial.

I used this instruction to accesses the NtGlobalFlag

lodsq gs:[rsi]

because their syntax didn't work on Visual studio.

But still, it didn't work.

While debugging I've noticed that the value of the **gs** register is set to 0x0000000000000000 while the **fs** register is set to a real value 0x0000007595377000.

I don't understand why the value of **GS** was zeroed, because it should have its value set on x64.

Comment: Note that `lodsq` modifies RSI.  Are you sure you want that?  `mov rax, gs:[rsi]` should work, or whatever the right MASM syntax is.  Or even `mov rax, gs:[60]`.

Comment: Note that `gs` and `fs` are only 16-bit segment selector registers.  I think you're talking about the internal FS and GS *base* addresses, accessible only via `rdgsbase`, or with `rdmsr` with `MSR_GS_BASE`, not directly with normal instructions.  "The value of GS" would be what you get from `mov eax, gs`, where `0` would be totally normal (because the OS sets the base via the MSR or `wrgsbase`, not by creating a GDT or LDT entry and doing `mov gs, eax`).  As for why Windows would have the FS and GS bases set that way, IDK; I don't have Windows or MSVC to check.

Comment: From what I understand lodsq  Load qword at address (R)SI into RAX and gs is used as a segment prefix override, Using the mov rax,gs results in a random value generated.

Comment: Yes, and then it increments RSI by 8.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lods:lodsb:lodsw:lodsd:lodsq

Comment: Yes, I have seen that in the debug window as well, is there a problem with that?

Comment: IDK, did you take that into account when you wrote `mov al, [rsi*2+rax-14h]` which uses RSI as part of the addressing mode?  You said something about porting it from some other instruction in a youtube video, so if `lodsq` was your idea then you might be breaking their code.

Comment: Oh, I've copied this code from the reference above,(The ultimate Anti Debugging Reference page 6 / 7 the code for x64 bit machines) My goal was to understand how this method works and how to implement it. So I didn't invent anything, this code is also used in other sources online like "Mastering Malware Analysis Page 185". But not in MASM syntax.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-ntcurrentteb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I still don't understand why the code posted here caused so many problems, As I said I just copied it from "The “[Ultimate”Anti-Debugging Reference](https://anti-reversing.com/Downloads/Anti-Reversing/The_Ultimate_Anti-Reversing_Reference.pdf)"

```
 push 60h
 pop rsi
 gs:lodsq ;Process Environment Block
 mov al, [rsi*2+rax-14h] ;NtGlobalFlag
 and al, 70h
 cmp al, 70h
 je being_debugged
```

But I've found a simpler solution that works perfectly.

As @"Peter Cordes" said I should be good with just accessing the value without lodsq like so -

```
mov rax, gs:[60h]
```

And after further investigation, I found this [reference](https://anti-debug.checkpoint.com/techniques/debug-flags.html#manual-checks-ntglobalflag),

Code -

```
mov rax, gs:[60h]
mov al, [rax+BCh]
and al, 70h
cmp al, 70h
jz  being_debugged
```

And I modified it a little bit for my program -

```
    .code
GetValueFromASM proc
    
    mov rax, gs:[60h]
    mov al, [rax+0BCh]
    and al, 70h
    cmp al, 70h
    jz  being_debugged
    mov rax,0
    ret

    being_debugged:
    mov rax, 1

    ret

GetValueFromASM endp
end
```

Just one thing to note -

When running inside visual studio 2017 the result returned was 0. Meaning no debugger attached which is False (Because I used the Local Windows Debugger).

**But when launching the process with WinDBG it did return 1 which means that it works.**

Comment: `push 60h` and `mov rax, gs:[60]` are using different addresses.

Comment: Sorry you are correct it was a typo. as you can in my code I used 60h.

Comment: If you want to return a `bool`, use `setz al` instead of branching to `mov` instructions.  (Sorry about the 60 vs. 60h typo in my original comment.  push 60h/pop/lodsq might be smaller code-size, but it's definitely not simpler so it seemed way over-complicated.)

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Answer (score 1):

64 bit Windows is apparently using `fs` to point to "per thread" memory, since `gs` is zero. I don't know what variables are kept in "per thread" memory, other than the seed value for rand(). You could debug a program that used rand(), and step through it in a disassembler window, to see how it is accessed.

The success of adding an anti-debugger feature to a program will depend on how much motivation there is to defeat it. The main issue is Windows remote debugging, and/or using a hacker installed device driver running in kernel mode to defeat an anti-debugger feature.